# $_GET parameter is not populated, even though URL has appropriate form

Tags: php, wordpress, url, get

I'm working on a new Wordpress site that is exhibiting some strange behaviour. I pass it a URL with GET parameters in it, and the `$_GET` parameter is not populated.  I see in the `$_SERVER` parameter that the `REQUEST_URI` has the full URL there, completed with the `?var=value` part, but no love in the `$_GET` variable.

The URL is being redirected with `mod_rewrite`, but given the fact that the `REQUEST_URI` shows the full thing, I'm thinking that's not the likely culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Taken care of.
The content of the variable here was itself a URL, encoding it was sufficient to get it passed through.  Could be it was picked off by some sort of security on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's old, but to whoever might read this : Wordpress won't use custom $_GET variables out of the box : you need to register these custom vars first in order for WP to be able to use them.

I'm no expert about that, but I remember finding very good tutorials about that. Search "adding new WP query vars"